# Объект в состояние Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Можно ли в состояние передать объект ?
Я передавал в состояние строчку, число, но вот объект не получается

```
const defaultState = {
    cash: 0,
    money: {},
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CASH':
            return { ...state, cash: (state.cash = action.payload) }

        case 'GET_CASH':
            return { ...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload }

        case 'ADD_MONEY':
            return { ...state, money: (state.money = action.payload) }

        case 'GET_MONEY':
            return { ...state, money: state.money - action.payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Из-за money: {} выдает ошибку
Вроде бы можно передать через массив объект

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно передать, нужно передавать (Простыми словами вернуть копию). А вы же мутируете, ногами заталкиваете payload в money так делать нельзя потому что вы потеряете возможно обновления состояния. Возможно стоит обратить внимание на изучение JavaScript прежде чем заходить в фреймворки (Не обижайтесь, мое мнение, может это просто опечатка).

```
const defaultState = {
    cash: 0,
    money: {},
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CASH':
            return { ...state, cash: action.payload }

        case 'GET_CASH':
            return { ...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload }

        case 'ADD_MONEY':
            return { ...state, money: action.payload }

        case 'GET_MONEY':
            return { ...state, money: state.money - action.payload } // Не будет работать, нельзя проводить математические операции с обьектами.

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```